# Configuring Torrent Softwares

Tags: bittorrent, transmission

I am having trouble configuring my torrent downloader.
I am running a dual boot of windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04.

On the windows partition, torrent download speeds easily reach 1MB/s while on Ubuntu they rarely reach more than 150kB/s.

I tried googling this problem, and it kept saying that you need to correctly configure your torrent software, but I could not find the details.

Right now, I am using Wine to run bittorrent, and am getting the speeds I was getting on Windows. The problem with this is that I can only download the files to my home folder, whereas with Transmission I would be able to download files to other partitions as well.

I have tried Transmission and KTorrent, but neither of them can match the same download speed.

One thing I have noticed is that both the Windows partition and the wine software create entries in the uPnP table in my router settings.

I was wondering if anybody could help me on this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly install Qbit-torrent.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hydr0g3n/qbittorrent-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qbittorrent
```

It has Utorrent like capabilities. Problem you are facing is because of wine.

Comment: can you explain/give referance why qbittorrent will give high speeds and not transmission/ktorrent?

Comment: Thank you.
This actually work.

But as above, can you please explain how this differs from the other software?

Comment: @Kashish/Samarth - I am not sure why it was not working fine with ktorrent/transmission. My point was to tell if you have linux based qbittorrent client than why need to install wine and then download torrents through it.

Comment: @That's right, but ktorrent and transmission are linux softwares , not windows/wine.Therefore the line `Problem you are facing is because of wine. ` in your answer doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: May be I took it wrongly. Apologies.